# Multiplicacion de numeros de un arreglo, n veces

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Quiero hacer una funcion que multiplique los digitos de un numero hasta que estos den un resultado menor que 10 y me devuelva la cantidad de multiplicaciones de los digitos del numero pasado por parametro que se realizaron...

> Ej: funcion(234) = 2  // porque 2*3*4 = 24,  2*4 = 8
>
> Ej: funcion(49) = 3  // porque  4*9 = 36,  3*6 = 18,  1*8=8

```js
function multiplicacionPersistente(num) {
    
    let multiplicacion = String(num).split('').map(numeros => (
        Number(numeros)
    )).reduce((anterior,actual) =>(
        anterior*actual
    ));
    

    return multiplicacion 
}


var respuesta = multiplicacionPersistente(999)
console.log(respuesta);
```

Seria algo asi como hacer esta funcion mia pero muchas veces.. recursiva... gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tienes el caso base: el número es menor que 10 (una cifra):

```
function multiplicaciones(n) {
  if (n<10) { return 0; }
  ...
}
```

El caso sobre el que iterar sería cuando n > 10:

```
...
else {
    return 1 + multiplicaciones(String(n).split('').map(s => +s).reduce((acc,n)=> n*acc));
  }
  ...
}
```

todo esto da:

```js
function multiplicaciones(n) {
  if (n<10) {
  console.log('no hay que multiplicar', n);
    return 0; 
  } else {
    console.log('Multiplicando los dígitos de',n);
    return 1 + multiplicaciones(String(n).split('').map(s => +s).reduce((acc,n)=> n*acc));
  }
}

console.log('Numero de multiplicaciones para 99:',multiplicaciones(99));
console.log('Numero de multiplicaciones para 555:',multiplicaciones(555));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @PabloLozano crack.. solo una duda en tu funcion `.map(s => +s)` con eso estas convirtiendo los elementos del arreglo a numero??

Comment: Los esta convirtiendo en números, ya que antes eran cadenas

Answer (score 4):

Una solución sin utilizar recursión podría ser la siguiente:

- Creamos una variable para llevar la cantidad de veces que se multiplica (`let counter = 0`).
- Mientras el número sea mayor o igual a 10:

  - Convertimos el número a una cadena (`eg: ''+num ==> string`)
  - Obtenemos los números que lo componen (`eg: string.split('') ==> array`)
  - A todos los números los multiplicamos entre si (`eg: array.reduce((acc, n) => acc * n) ==> number`)
  - Incrementamos la variable (`eg: counter++`).

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function multiplicacionPersistente(num) {
  let counter = 0;
  while (num >= 10) {
    num = ('' + num).split('').reduce((acc, n) => acc * n);
    counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}

console.log('Cantidad de multiplicaciones:', multiplicacionPersistente(999));
```

Comment: Gracias @Marcos me gusta esta solucion es elegante

Comment: Habría que ver en este caso particular, pero me parece que la iteraración es bastante mas óptima que la recursión.

Comment: Espera, ¿que no el problema era hallar el numero de iteraciones? por que la función regresa el ultimo numero de la multiplicación (para 999 debería ser 4 no 2)

Comment: @the-breaker no se le escapa nada... sigue siendo mas rapido sin recursion

Comment: el rendimiento de la segunda funcion mejora si se hace `${n}...`. `String(n)` hasta un 98% vs 100%

Comment: Dicho sea de paso, `[...${n}]` me parece una muy buena forma de pasar de numero a array.

Comment: @Emeeus, estamos a full =). Si, al parecer hacer `[...'${num}']` es mas rápido que `'${n}'.split('')`

Answer (score 2):

Una forma sencilla de hacer tu función recursiva sería así:

```
function multiplicacionPersistente(num) {

    let multiplicacion = String(num).split('').map(numeros => (
        Number(numeros)
    )).reduce((anterior,actual) =>(
        anterior*actual
    ));
    if(multiplicacion < 10)
     multiplicacionPersistente(multiplicacion)
    return multiplicacion 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues aunque no lo crean existe un metodo aun mas simple con menos lineas, usando un `for`:

```js
  function multiplicacionPersistente (numero) {
    for (cont = 0; numero>10; cont++)
      numero=String(numero).split('').reduce((a,n)=> a*n);
    return cont;
  }
  
  console.log(multiplicacionPersistente(999));
  console.log(multiplicacionPersistente(234));
  console.log(multiplicacionPersistente(49));
```

Así queda la forma mas optima posible, saludos.

Comment: Number tiene una propiedad toString()  tambien es valido `numero.toString().split('').reduce((a,n)=> a*n);`

Comment: @JackNavaRow gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: Deberías indicar que `cont` es una variable local, de lo contrario estas definiendo una variable global

Comment: @Marcos gracias, lo tomo en cuenta, no acostumbro manejar `let`, he tenido problemas con ese en el pasado.

Comment: Si no te gusta `let`, podes usar `var`, ejemplo `for (var cont = 0;...`

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, solo que usaría el recién descubierto `[...'${numero}']` y un `var` en `cont`,  `let`  no es posible porque se necesita fuera del `for`.